# blank/white page error in react js app ( stopped working in chrome and edge all of a sudden)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cross-browser, cloud-foundry, pcf

I have a react app which is in production for few years now, everything was working just fine but all of a sudden a it has stopped working (only a particular function of the app) as mentioned below -

There's a table on the UI which contain a list of attachments/documents and a anchor tag as a link to the attachment, on click of a link it calls a spring boot API which return byte stream with headers as below -

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    "attachment; filename=\"" + document.getName() + "\"")
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream")
            .body(documentData.getData());
```

This was all working so far in all browsers including IE, chrome and edge and it is still working in IE browser but has stopped working in chrome and edge browsers. When I click on the attachment link in chrome and edge it just shows a blank/white page and the document doesn't download.

When I check in the developer console, it shows that API has worked just fine with 200 as status and in response it shows some html code which refers to few assets (css and js files), content type shows as text/html though api returns application/octet-stream.

Now this all still works in IE but has stopped working in chrome and edge browsers, if I launch the app in local dev server running on localhost 3002 then the download works in chrome and edge as well.

Please can someone advise what could be the issue and what can be done to get this working.

This is my project structure -
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Xjq.png)

Response headers returned by download api call are -

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 1005
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 28 Apr 2022 15:16:18 GMT
Dws-Correlation-Id: 5d39b7aa0d734cf48090ce584d9d05be
Expires: 0
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Apr 2022 16:07:58 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Vcap-Request-Id: fc375cb0-25cd-498d-7620-381e873164e3
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any error in console in Edge/Chrome? I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **run** and **reproduce** the issue? You can use some online code editor like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to show the demo so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: This all works on the local server (on all browsers), when I deploy this to PCF it stops working in chrome and edge browsers but continue to work in IE. In console I see the download API returns content type as text/html instead of application/octet-stream, in response tab I see some html code instead of bytestream returned by API and there are few errors (GET net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)) for not being able to load some js and css files. Because this all works well on local dev server, just thinking if there could be any configurations/changes on PCF causing these errors ??

Comment: From your description, it looks like the issue should be related with PCF. I think you're using SAP Cloud Foundry. I suggest that you can ask the question in [SAP Community](https://community.sap.com/) so that you can get more help.

Comment: it's running on pivotal cloud foundary, any suggestion what could be checked ? thanks

Comment: has anyone faced similar issue, any other suggestions please ?

Comment: It might be pivotal cloud foundry's issue. Besides, you can try to test in other browsers like Firefox, if it works well in all the other browsers and only fails in Edge and Chrome, it also might be an issue with chromium. You can report the issue in [chromium issue tracker site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).